# Difference hot-swap bay cage with and without tray (trayless)

Tags: hardware-rec, hotswapping

What exactly is the difference between a *normal* hot-swap bay cage and a *trayless* hot-swap bay cage?

I know that a *trayless* hot-swap cage looks like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVvgZi2Injc). So what's the difference with a normal one?

Here is a price comparison I found on a hardware website (so trayless is *$59* more expensive):

[image]

Comment: tray-less MAY mean you need to buy the trays separately, but the item in your video is designed to not requre trays. Trays are just a small "case-like" box (usually open on top) that works with your enclosure to let the disk slide in and lock into place, so you don't have to fiddle with screws (which would be hard to do with a hot-swap enclosure).

Comment: @FrankThomas, I don't think that is the case as the trayless versions are more expensive (I discovered on some hardware websites)

Comment: As I said, the one in your video is designed to work without trays. I certianly wouldn't pay extra for trayless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical difference.  The trayless ones take up slightly less space but it's harder to get the drives in and out of it.  The tray ones have a convenient handle for pulling the drive out of the enclosure.  Also the tray models tend to have an activity light on each tray to indicate drive power and access.  The trayless models usually have just one light that blinks for any drive in the enclosure (although that's not always true).